# Scanning the characters properly except '+' and '-'

Tags: c, char, scanf

I am trying to scan an arithmetic expression like : `4+3-2*6*(3+4/2)#`

What I tried is following code.  It's running fine and scanning each character properly except `'+'` and `'-'`.

> Why it is not scanning only two particular characters!

```
void scan(){

    int n,tmp,digit_no;
    char c;
    scanf("%c",&c);

    while(c!='#'){  


            if(isdigit(c))
            {

                tmp=c;
                scanf(" %d",&n);
                digit_no=numPlaces(n);
                n=(tmp-48)*ipow(10,digit_no)+n; 
                push_n(n);
                n=0;        
            }
            else if(c=='+' || c=='-' || c=='*' || c=='/' || c=='(' || c==')' || c=='=' || c=='^') 
                push_o(c);

        scanf("%c",&c);

        }


}
```

Comment: Why don;t you check the return value of scanf()?

Comment: checked a lot of times !! It's not scanning '+' and '-'.

Comment: Tell me, do you understand what does it mean by return value of a function?

Comment: @SouravGhosh what's your point?

Comment: Check for success of scanf()

Comment: `scanf("%c",&c);` -->`scanf(" %c",&c);` notice the additional space to consume whitespace from previous keyboard entries (example `newline`) left in the input buffer. Notably from `scanf(" %d",&n);` which - unnecessarily - includes that space. Format `%d` consumes leading whitespace. Format `%c` does not.

Comment: But this should happen for each character .. why only in the case of '+' and '-'?

Comment: There is no sense in downvoting the que. if you guys don't know the answer!

Comment: Downvotes are because you didn't post enough information for anyone to even confirm that the problem exists, let alone solve it. Based on what you have posted, the best explanation is that you are just mistaken about what you are seeing.   Your question should include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the exact input you provided to your program, the exact output you saw, and an explanation of how the output differed from what you expected.

Comment: Your code probably misbehaves at the start of a string: the `scanf("%c",&c);` commands are supposed to be scanning an operator, but your string actually starts with `4`.  (What if it started with `45` ? ) Then you go on to do the `%d` scan when the next character in the stream is actually an operator.  If your test string was `4*3+2-1` for example you probably would not observe the same behaviour regarding `+` and `-`.

Comment: @M.M Agree in general with your DV comment.  Yet OP's problem is parsing `"3-2"` and `"3+4"` incorrectly with `scanf("%c",&c) ... scanf(" %d",&n);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not get a `char`, test for a digit, scan an `int` and then try to put them together.  This fails the code's intent with input like for input like `"3-2"`,  `"1 23"`, `"1+23"` as well explained by [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35210439/2410359) as `scanf("%d",&n)` is consuming the `+ -`.

Instead put the digit back into `stdin` and then scan for the `int`.

```
 if(isdigit(c)) {
   ungetc(c, stdin);
   scanf("%d",&n);  // cannot fail as first character is a digit - may overflow though
   push_n(n);
   n=0;        
 }
```

Also suggest to detect `EOF` and use `is...()` functions correctly.

```
// char c;
// scanf("%c",&c);
int c;
// while(c!='#'){  
while((c = fgetc(stdin)) !='#' && c != EOF) {  
  ...
  // scanf("%c",&c);
}
```

Detail: `is...()` expects an `int` in the range of `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Calling them with a `char` is a problem when the value is negative.

Comment: Yup, this is the answer, I was looking for. Thanks dude!!

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken: `scanf()` *is* scanning the '+' and '-'.  It is simply scanning them as *part of* the decimal number that follows.

With your example input, the program first scans a '4', which is a digit.  It then proceeds to execute `scanf(" %d",&n);`, which scans the next two characters, "+3", as the number 3, because fields described by `%d` may optionally have a leading sign character, either '-' or '+'.  The scanning stops at the first '-', since a decimal number cannot contain an internal or trailing '-', and indeed, the '-' is scanned as the next character.  You would see different results for '-' or '+' following a two-digit number or a parenthesis.

Overall, your approach to scanning numbers is fundamentally flawed.  Not only does it run aground on the optional sign character, but I see no way it can do the right thing when the second-most-significant digit of the number you are trying to read is a '0'.  That is, your approach cannot distinguish "401" from "41".  You cannot successfully scan the tail of a number as a number in its own right without losing information you need.

Comment: Yupp!! It explains my mistake.. Is there anyway to make it correct, with a little bit of changes.

Comment: @davidwatson, you should probably scan each character individually instead of trying to shortcut as you do with `scanf(" %d")`.  As a consequence of the needed restructuring, that probably will allow you to dump the `numPlaces()` and `ipow()` functions.  Getting rid of those would be a win, but I'm uncertain whether you would characterize the overall result as "a little bit of changes".